# get data from emberjs store.find

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a route with model person:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('person');
  }
});
```

I want to modify the data in this model in my controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    justLog: function(){
      this.get('model') // ???
    }
  }
});
```

but `this.get('model');` returns `Class {store: Class, isLoaded: true, manager: Class, isUpdating: false, __ember1463955537869: "ember357"…}` and i cant get the data out of it.

Comment: That looks correct. What have you tried to actually do with the model? Keep in mind `store.findAll` returns an array.

Comment: Try something like `console.log(this.get('model.firstObject'))` for fun.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but shouldn't the route's model hook read `this.store.findAll('person')`; and not `this.store.findAll('function');`?

Comment: `this.get('model.firstObject')` actually works, returns the first object which supposed to be in the list, how can i iterate over all these elements?

Comment: `this.get('model').forEach` or `this.get('model').map`, like you would a regular array.

Comment: Also, in your handlebars template you can do `{{#each model as |person|}}<p>Name: {{ person.name }}</p>{{/each}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices, the first one:

```
this.get('model').forEach(function(element){
  element.get('propertyName');
})
```

The second one:

```
this.get('model').map(function(element){
  return element.get('propertyName');
})
```

Remeber that the map functor returns a brand new array.

To modify the values you should use `.set('propertyName', value);` function.