# Ember: Cannot access model data in controller/template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I am new to ember framework and i have problems or doubts in accessing ember-data. I am using ember-cli and ember-cli-mirage for demo purposes.

**config.js**

```
export default function() {
this.get('/newcontracts', function(db, request) {

 return {
   data:[{
     "type": "newcontracts",
     "id": 1,
     "attributes": {
         "department-type": ["Legal", "Sales"],
         "agreement-type": ["Service Agreement", "Purchase"],
         "renewal-type": ["One time", "None"]
     }
  }]
 }
});
```

**Ember Store**

```
export default Model.extend({
   "type": "",
   "department-type": attr(""),
   "agreement-type": attr(""),
   "renewal-type": attr("")
});
```

**Router**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function(){
        console.log(this.get('store').findAll('newcontract')) // outputs ember class
        return this.get('store').findAll('newcontract');
     });
```

**Controller**

```
 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  details: Ember.computed('model', function() {
   return this.store.peekRecord('new-contract', 1) // --> outputs ember class
    //console.log(this.store.peekRecord('new-contract', 1).get('department-type)) ---> desired output(array)
  })
  departmentDetails: Ember.computed('model', function() {
    this.details.get('department-type') ; ///error
  })

});
```

**Template**

```
{{log "model" details}} --> ember class
{{log "model" model}} --> ember class
{{log "model" model.department-type}} --> undefined
```

> Can't I access departmentDetails like that? I get the desired data if I use the commented line in details property. Should I get the each data separately from the store? Also, logging the value in model gives an Ember class.
>
> Even in the template file, I cannot get the value of model.department-type, etc.

I get the data in the Ember chrome inspector correctly.
Fyi, I am using ember 2.5.1. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Inisde your model what is the idea behind having type field. You are using JsonApi adapter right? Also your properties are arrays, Legal..Sales...Do you want to consume the, like array. I can provide some tips but not sure how do you want to consume department-type...inside select?

Comment: If you don't want to specify a transform, you should use `atr()`, not `attr("")`. You also need to do `this.get('details')` in `departementDetails`.

Comment: Both model and details are ember enumerables so you can enumerate it to get the data.. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380384/get-data-from-emberjs-store-find/37408910#37408910

Answer (score 1):

`this.get('store').findAll('newcontract');` gives you an array of newcontract.

Logging `model[0].department-type` in template will print the `department-type`.

To answer your question, you are not accessing `departmentDetails` anywhere, instead you are creating one in the controller.

Also, you cannot directly access a computed property like `details`, you should always use `get()`. So its `this.get('details').get('department-type')` not `this.details.get('department-type')`